# How to select second split of column data from oracle database

Tags: oracle

I want to select the data from a Oracle table, whereas the table columns contains the data as , [ex : key,value] separated values; so here I want to select the second split i.e, value

table column data as below :

```
column_data
++++++++++++++
asper,worse
tincher,good
golder
null                       -- null values need to eliminate while selection
www,ewe
```

from the above data, desired output like below:

```
column_data
+++++++++++++
worse
good
golder
ewe
```

Please help me with the query

Comment: Don't store  column records as a comma separated values. It is bound to cause  you problems forever.

Comment: I would second the comment by @KaushikNayak.  What you present violates every design principle known to man.  You need to spend some time studying 'data normalization' and 'Third Normal Form'. Your difficulty in getting the data you want is a direct result of the poor table design.

Answer (score 1):

According to data you provided, here are two options:

- `result1`: regular expressions one (get the 2nd *word* if it exists; otherwise, get the 1st one)
- `result2`: `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'asper,worse'  from dual union all
  3     select 'tincher,good' from dual union all
  4     select 'golder'       from dual union all
  5     select null           from dual union all
  6     select 'www,ewe'      from dual
  7    )
  8  select col,
  9         nvl(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2), regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1,1 )) result1,
 10         --
 11         nvl(substr(col, instr(col, ',') + 1), col) result2
 12  from test
 13  where col is not null;

COL          RESULT1              RESULT2
------------ -------------------- --------------------
asper,worse  worse                worse
tincher,good good                 good
golder       golder               golder
www,ewe      ewe                  ewe

SQL>
```

Comment: *"According to data you provided, here are two options: "* indeed topicstarter keep in mind that `nvl(substr(col, instr(col, ',') + 1)` does not work on `asper,worse,other` as it would select `worse,other`

Comment: Hi LF, thanks for responding; my table data contains only key,value; and I need the result as first split in first row and second split in second row; if the data not contains , separator; I have to select that as well and put it in a row

Comment: You're welcome. Query I wrote returns result you initially described. If the requirement differs from that, would you mind posting an **example** of what you are saying? Please, edit the question to do that and post a comment (otherwise there'll be no alert and I won't have a look at it).